# java.sql.SQLXML.free() causing connection leak

Tags: java, db2, spring-jdbc, sqlxml

I am using JdbcTemplate to create SQLXML object:

```
SQLXML sqlXML = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().createSQLXML();
```

and, after using the resource I release it in the finally block as below:

```
finally {
    try{
       if (sqlXML != null)
          sqlXML.free();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // log error
    }
}
```

This however leads to connection leak when my application is running.

What am I doing wrong and how can this be handled?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you freeing all other resources that are allocated by the connection during use when they are exhausted or no longer needed, such as result-sets and any other handles?. Since you have the code, it is your job to find the source of the leak!

Comment: jdbcTemplate implicitly will do the cleanup and/or release resources , right?